# Cannot find my own packages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS users,

I don't have any experience with ROS but I want to learn to use it.
I just installed it in Ubuntu 12.04 (fuerte), follow some steps in the tutorials, but I got stuck.

In "Creating a ROS Package (rosbuild)" it says to create a new package:
**$ roscreate-pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp**

and check if ROS can find it.
**$ rospack find beginner_tutorials**

It can't.
And I don't understand this:
"If this fails, it means ROS can't find your new package, which may be an issue with your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Please consult the installation instructions for setup from SVN or from binaries, depending how you installed ROS. If you've created or added a package that's outside of the existing package paths, you will need to amend your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable to include that new location. Try re-sourcing your setup.sh in your fuerte_workspace."

First I didn't have a ROS_WORKSPACE. So I made some research and used "export" to do it. Now **root@to-vb:/opt/ros/fuerte_workspace#** is my workspace.
And it's where I created my new package (not in **$ cd ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox** as it's said).

Second, if it's an issue with ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, of course I created a package that's outside of the existing package paths, and **$ cd ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox** is out of it! Then how do I amend it?

My Ubuntu is in a virtual machine. I deleted and created a new one to install ROS again and it is still the same. So, I concluded that this tutorial steps are not coherent with my system.

Could anyone help me, please?
Nat0ne

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48484/cannot-find-my-own-packages/) by [Nat0ne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3614/nat0ne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First off, I would suggest to set your workspace in somewhere `~/`, and not in `/opt`. It is preferable to work in a directory where you only need standard user permissions.

Here is an example how to set your workspace to `~/ros`, and also make sure the workspace is part of the package path. I have this appended at the end of my `~/.bashrc` file.

```
ROS_WORKSPACE=$HOME/ros
export ROS_WORKSPACE 

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_WORKSPACE:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

If you now create your packages in `~/ros`, everything should work fine.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-18**:
Manually managing ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is not recommended. The best way is to use rosws. The relevant wiki page can be found [here](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays).